# Print entire Block if multiple strings are found inside Start ---End

Tags: text-processing, awk, hp-ux

My Raw log file similar to production log i have tweaked this,

```
Block f1
PCO Blockf1
tray:school       SAM :XP 
        X/Y       DUPL
   KEY  Z/Z
Block f2
PCO Blockf2
tray:school       SAM :XP 
        D/D       DUPL
    KEY D/D
Block f3
PCO Blockf3
tray:school       SAM :AP 
        X/Y       DUPL
   KEY  Z/Z

-----cont.. more than 800 records
```

expected result with applied filters as follows:
condition1:If SAM :XP is found with Z/Z above X/Y(FYI...Z/Z above row contains X/Y) then print like this

```
Block f1
PCO Blockf1
tray:school       SAM :XP 
        X/Y       DUPL
   KEY  Z/Z
```

condition2:IF SAM :XPis found with D/D above D/D(FYI...D/D above row contains D/D) then print

```
Block f2
PCO Blockf2
tray:school       SAM :XP 
        D/D       DUPL
    KEY D/D
```

like these it has traverse 800 records and print these output to junk.txt.
NOTE: Rows may decrease or increase Here Block is treated as starting and ending, in-between PCO BlockXX is there, script should not consider that block ignore that.

Thanks I tried so far  awk 'BEGIN{RS="Block\n"; ORS=RS} $0=="" || /KEY:ZZ/ && /XY/ {print}' raw.txt >> junk.txt.

> I am using HP-UX

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587218/print-lines-between-two-regex-using-sed

Comment: Are you sure that you need END section (`Block f3`) in each block because in the same time it can be START section for next block too

Comment: Yes we need Block f3 same time it may be starting point also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost standart task for sed

```
sed '
    /^Block/! D
    :1
    N
    $!{
       /\n\s*KEY/! b1
    }
    \%SAM.*D/D.*D/D\|SAM.*X/Y.*Z/Z%! d
    ' log
```

produce

```
Block f1
PCO Blockf1
tray:school       SAM :XP 
        X/Y       DUPL
   KEY  Z/Z
Block f2
PCO Blockf2
tray:school       SAM :XP 
        D/D       DUPL
    KEY D/D
Block f3
PCO Blockf3
tray:school       SAM :AP 
        X/Y       DUPL
   KEY  Z/Z
```

Comment: as speed as bullet thanks...I have done mistake while posting log i didnot exposed production log but now see my edits i am pasting a log similar to production log,  i have tweaked script but is not working my production log.

Comment: If you need to use `/` inside regexp you'd have to change divider to any other symbol, i.e. as in my edited answer `¦`

Comment: you caught me at right thing i need to keep only this much not Block f3 i have edited.

Comment: Sorry for `¦` — it cannot be applicable, use other

Comment: Can you relook at my edit once, In NOTE i have mentioned rows are dynamic

Comment: @chandu See edited but note that is final. You can and have to do task by yourself. We would show the right direction only.

Comment: Thanks Costas i will take from here but you almost gave me exact solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54496/discussion-between-chandu-and-costas).

Comment: script is printing some negative results like case1:If SAM :XP and Z/Z above X/Y is there then its has to print only results regarding SAM:XP but it is printing SAM: AP also where under AP Z/Z above X/Y is there the main filter is SAM :XP it has to look for this key and and check the Z/Z above X/Y

Comment: @chandu You are free to modify the script accordint to your needs (for the above just substitute  all `SAM` by `SAM :XP` in the code)

Comment: I did costas after I reached you it is printing some negative results.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '
  /^Block/,/[ ]KEY[ ]/!d;           # reject noninteresting data
  H; /^Block/h; /[ ]KEY[ ]/!d;      # stuff block in hold space
  g;                                # retrieve block when block ends
  /SAM[ ]*:XP\n/!d;                 # filter out block since no SAM XP
  /\n[ ]*KEY[ ]*\([DZ]\)\/\1$/!d;   # filter out block since no key D/D|Z/Z
  n;p;s/^/\n/;D;                    # print block, print next line, go back
' yourfile
```

**Ouput**

```
Block f1
PCO Blockf1
    tray:school       SAM :XP
    X/Y       DUPL
    KEY  Z/Z
Block f2
Block f2
PCO Blockf2
    tray:school       SAM :XP
    D/D       DUPL
    KEY D/D
Block f3
```

Comment: Rakesh sorry see my edits i have posted different log.